# Bash associative array size

Tags: linux, bash, associative-array

Is there a way to get size of associative array in bash:

```
declare -A array
```

...without iterating through the elements?

The size of interest is both: just number of elements, and memory amount it consumes?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`${#array[@]}` would return you the size of the array.

```
$ declare -A array
$ array[foo]='something'
$ array[bar]='blah'
$ array[42]='nothing'
$ echo ${#array[@]}
3
```

Comment: oh right, totally forgot, thank you. Any idea on resource consumption when the array becomes of substantial size?

Comment: @wick I don't think that you can determine the resource consumption, though.  Consider an alternate approach if your arrays are becoming really *huge*.

Comment: Reference: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html (scroll down to *Variable length / Substring removal*).

Answer (score 15):

You can use `${#array[@]}` to get the number of elements.

I don't think it is possible to get the amount of memory it consumes however.